# How to render Bootstrap DateTime Picker within a Panel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem using Bootstrap DateTime picker when nested within a panel.

The datetime calender and datetime hours and minutes components render an "empty" box when clicked.

Here's an example to show you what I mean

[image]

I am using the latest Bootstrap frameworks and components (Bootstrap framework V3.3.4) with Bootstrap 3 DateTimePicker v4.14.30.

Here is my HTML code

```
<div class="panel panel-primary">
<div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title">Basic Search Criteria</h3>
    <form id="frm1">
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">Start Date</span>
            <input type="text" id='searchStartDate' name="searchStartDate" class="form-control" placeholder="Search start date" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
            <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon2">Start Time</span>
            <input type="text" id='searchStartTime' name="searchStartTime" class="form-control" placeholder="Search start time" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
          </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

and here is the Jquery code for the date and time input fields

```
$(function () {
            $('#searchStartDate').datetimepicker({
                format: 'DD-MM-YYYY',
               });
        });

        $(function () {
            $('#searchStartTime').datetimepicker({
                format: 'HH:mm', 
              });
        });
```

> If I move the two statements
>
> ```
> <input type="text" id='searchStartDate'
> ```
>
> and
>
> ```
> <input type="text" id='searchStartTime'
> ```
>
> outside of the panel div both date control components render find.

But, when I move them into the Panel div, the DateTime calender and DateTime hour and minutes boxes render empty / or blank ~ as in the example above.

I have used the DOM Explorer and have managed at least to find an issue / problem within the Bootstrap.CSS that **suggests** the problem is with the div.panel-heading statement, specifically this

[image]

If I uncheck the color selection within the DOM Explorer I am then able to render the calender control as follows

[image]

But, this then leaves me with two new problems

1) the color of the panel title has changed from white to black

2) the default color of my calender control has changed to black

I have considered making an update to the bootstrap.css file to remove the color attribute div.panel-heading ~ but If I do that then I will lose the default setting on any other times I use a panel. Also, I am worried that if I did make a manual change, if I then say, in 12 months time download and use the next latest and greatest incarnation of Bootstrap ~ I will lose any changes I have made and my controls will not render again.

Does anyone know of what I can do to fix this, what is the 'best' approach for overriding the default settings so that I do not lose any 'fix' in future?

I tried to implement the solutions mention by @loni and @Jason but my calendar box still renders empty

[image]

However, I can render a calender control (but the styling has been lost) by changing the div class="panel panel-primary" to just div class="panel" as follows

[image]

but as you can see, of course now my panel has lost its formatting, the calendar does render, but not in it's correct color format.

Comment: add a css rule of your website that targets the calendar's id and add !important like  "color:black !important;"

Comment: In addition to the suggestion @loli made you could target the `#basic-addon1` span and set its color property to white instead of the whole panel.

Comment: @loli and @ Jason, thank you both for your suggestions but unfortunately what ever I try, my calender control still renders 'emtpy'. I'm updating yesterdays post with some new information, maybe you could take a look and point me in the right direction. I'm totally lost right now.

Comment: I remember having a problem with z-index a few weeks ago. Any inherited z-index that would mess up with the datetimepicker ? Btw I believe this is a legit bug that should be reported to bootstrap or the datetimepicker team (if you don't have any other custom styles that may interfere)

Comment: @ Cyril, thank you ~ I will research z-index and I think I probably will make a report to the datetimepicker team. I'll let you now what comes back.

Comment: I'm sure that if you make a jsfiddle with the problem we'll be able to fix it in no time

Comment: @ loli, I have made a jsfiddle @ https://jsfiddle.net/M70_536/j64uLrjd/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is simple as follows

1) close the panel header div.

2) wrap the panel contents within a panel-body div.

```
<div class="panel panel-primary">
<div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title">Basic Search Criteria</h3> </div>
<div class="panel-body">
    <form id="frm1">
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">Start Date</span>
            <input type="text" id='searchStartDate' name="searchStartDate" class="form-control" placeholder="Search start date" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
            <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon2">Start Time</span>
            <input type="text" id='searchStartTime' name="searchStartTime" class="form-control" placeholder="Search start time" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
            <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon3">End Date</span>
            <input type="text" id='searchEndDate' name="searchEndDate" class="form-control" placeholder="Search end date" aria-describedby="basic-addon3">
            <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon4">End Time</span>
            <input type="text" id='searchEndTime' name="searchEndTime" class="form-control" placeholder="Search end time" aria-describedby="basic-addon4">
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon5">Job Name</span>
            <input type="text" id='jobName' name="jobName" class="form-control" placeholder="Search job name" aria-describedby="basic-addon5">
            <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon8">Application</span>
            <input type="text" id="applicationName" name="applicationName" class="form-control" placeholder="Search by application" aria-describedby="basic-addon8">
            <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon7">Table</span>
            <input type="text" id="tableName" name="tableName" class="form-control" placeholder="Search by schedule table" aria-describedby="basic-addon7">
            <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon6">Server</span>
            <input type="text" id='serverName' name="serverName" class="form-control" placeholder="Search server name" aria-describedby="basic-addon6">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

An example of the correctly rendered solution

[image]